# PostGIS: function ST_AsRaster does not exist. Even using examples from the docs

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-12

I'm trying to convert geometries to images, and the functions to do so don't seem to exist.

The following example is from the [ST_AsRaster Docs](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) WHich specify the requirements are `Availability: 2.0.0 - requires GDAL >= 1.6.0.`

```sql
SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1,5),10),150, 150));
```

This results in:

> ERROR:  function st_asraster(geometry, integer, integer) does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1,5),10),150,...

I found some info that points towards needing GDAL drivers, however, when I try:

```sql
SELECT short_name, long_name FROM ST_GdalDrivers();
```

I get:

> ERROR:  function st_gdaldrivers() does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT short_name, long_name FROM ST_GdalDrivers();

---

I have no idea where to even go to try solving this, why don't the functions exist, was there some config I needed to add, some doc I didn't read?

Even the https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html seems to suggest that it should "just work"?

---

This is installed from the package manager on Ubuntu 20.0.4.

**Version Info `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();`:**

```
POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] 
PGSQL="120" 
GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " 
PROJ="6.3.1" 
LIBXML="2.9.4" 
LIBJSON="0.13.1" 
LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" 
WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have forgotten to install the `postgis_raster` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
```

This extension is new in PostGIS 3.0; before that, its objects were part of the `postgis` extension.

[The documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/postgis_installation.html#install_short_version) mentions that:

> Once postgis is installed, it needs to be enabled in each individual database you want to use it in.
>
> ```
> psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
>
> -- if you built with raster support and want to install it --
> psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;"
> ```

Comment: This was it. Do the docs mention this somewhere, like a list of extensions? First time using Postgres or postgis and this was.... less than obvious.

Comment: I have added a reference.